# How to use get data from a servlet to a JSP

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, el

I'm new to Java server programming, and I'm trying to use Google app engine.

The following code is in a servlet:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("message", "Hi from servlet!");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/my_page.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

And the following code is in `my_page.jsp`:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("message") %>
```

Where I would expect to see `Hi from servlet!` on the resulting page, I see `null`.

(If I try using `${message}`, I get no output at all)

What is the correct way to get data from a servlet to a JSP?

Comment: This is the correct way. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors, just a "null" on the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the request URL (the one as you see in browser's address bar) point to an URL which matches the URL pattern of the servlet as configured in `web.xml`, not to the URL of the JSP file itself. Best would be to put the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder so that you can't "accidently" invoke it without invoking the servlet.

By the way, the `${message}` is the correct way and should be preferred over old fashioned *scriptlets*.